# Excel VBA - FormulaArray error (for LARGER(IF()))

Tags: vba, excel, formula

I use the =LARGE(IF(...);1) function in Excel, from VBA, and I use the FormulaArray. Beacause I get a problem, I did specific functions for the cells:

```
Sheets("OEVK").Range("J314").FormulaLocal = "=LARGER(IF(jelolt_lista!$C:$C=OEVK!B314;jelolt_lista!$M:$M);1)"
 Sheets("OEVK").Range("J315").FormulaLocal = "=LARGER(IF(jelolt_lista!$C:$C=OEVK!B315;jelolt_lista!$M:$M);2)"
 Sheets("OEVK").Range("J316").FormulaLocal = "=LARGER(IF(jelolt_lista!$C:$C=OEVK!B316;jelolt_lista!$M:$M);3)"
 Sheets("OEVK").Range("J317").FormulaLocal = "=LARGER(IF(jelolt_lista!$C:$C=OEVK!B317;jelolt_lista!$M:$M);1)"
 Sheets("OEVK").Range("J318").FormulaLocal = "=LARGER(IF(jelolt_lista!$C:$C=OEVK!B318;jelolt_lista!$M:$M);2)"
 Sheets("OEVK").Range("J319").FormulaLocal = "=NAGY(HA(jelolt_lista!$C:$C=OEVK!B319;jelolt_lista!$M:$M);3)"
 Sheets("OEVK").Range("J2:J319").FormulaArray = Sheets("OEVK").Range("J2:J319").Formula
```

I use this in hungarian.
But after the macro running, the relevant links (B2, B4, B6 instead of B2, B3, B4) in cells are incorrect, and I don't know, why.

The result in cells: (NAGY = LARGER, HA = IF)

```
J2: {=NAGY(HA(jelolt_lista!$C:$C=OEVK!B2;jelolt_lista!$M:$M);1)}
J3: {=NAGY(HA(jelolt_lista!$C:$C=OEVK!B4;jelolt_lista!$M:$M);2)}
J4: {=NAGY(HA(jelolt_lista!$C:$C=OEVK!B6;jelolt_lista!$M:$M);3)}
```

Can you help us in this problem? I tried with more less range, but it didn't help me...

Thank you for your help!

Best regards,
N

Comment: Hello, Can you describe in words what you are trying to do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There does indeed seem to be a bug in bulk converting range of formulas into array formulas. The row-by-row progrssion starts skipping rows; e.g. B2, B3, B4, ... becomes B2, B4, B6, ... Here are two alternatives.

Individually:

```
Sub Macro3()
    Dim f As Long

    With Worksheets("OEVK")
        For f = 2 To 319
            .Cells(f, "J").FormulaArray = _
              "=LARGE(IF(jelolt_lista!$C:$C=OEVK!B" & f & ", jelolt_lista!$M:$M), " & (f - 2) Mod 3 + 1 & ")"
        Next f
    End With
End Sub
```

Write one then fill down,

```
Sub Macro2()
    With Worksheets("OEVK")
        .Cells(2, "J").FormulaArray = _
          "=LARGE(IF(jelolt_lista!$C:$C=OEVK!B2, jelolt_lista!$M:$M), MOD(ROW(2:2)-2, 3) + 1)"
        .Range(.Cells(2, "J"), .Cells(319, "J")).FillDown
    End With
End Sub
```

I would agree that your full column ranges need to be cut down to the extents of the actual data.

Comment: I did not know about this. Something like a heisenbug? Is it seemingly random when it occurs?

Comment: First time I've run into it myself. Had to run full test bench to confirm. Haven't run anymore tests but I will be keeping an eye out on this one.